# SVG coding envornment

Tags: software-recommendation, svg

I'm starting to learn SVG graphics coding, but I'm looking for something with a WYSIWYG kind of thing. Does such a thing exist?

And what would you advise me to make the learning process faster?

Answer (score 1):

I think [SVG-edit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) sounds perfect for what you are describing. The main interface is a WYSIWYG:

[image: SVG-Edit WYSIWYG]

Clicking the `Edit Source` button in the top left brings up the code editor:

[image: SVG-Edit Code Editor]

[**Try it out**](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html)